# MVC 5 chart helper ( does not appear within a view)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with chart helper ASP.NET MVC 5, it does not appear within the view.I use MVC5 & EF6 Here is my code

Controller ->

```
private ActionResult StatusChartPie()
    {
        var res = db.StatusStatistics;
        new Chart(width: 300, height: 250)
            .AddTitle("Projects Status")
            .AddLegend()
            .AddSeries("Default", chartType: "pie", xValue: res, xField:"Status", yValues: res, yFields:"ProjectsCounts")
            .Write("bmp");
        return null ;
    }
```

View ->
I tried both

```
    <img src="@Url.Action("StatusChartPie","Projects")" alt="StatusChart" />

    <img src="/Projects/StatusChartPie" />
```

Comment: why are you returning null?

Comment: because it does not suppose to return anything. just doing its job ( making a bmp file). As I think :)

Comment: so why you put this action as a `src` for `img`? this doesn't make any sense

Comment: I don't know what is suppose to return :(

Comment: is supposed to return the image if this is what you want to display there